# Iterate csv file and find matches

Tags: java

I have the following csv file structure:

| car | score | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Opel | 30 | 43 |
| Volvo | 500 | 434 |
| Kia | 50 | 3 |
| Toyota | 4 | 4 |
| Mazda | 5000 | 4 |

I want to find numbers match. For example if 3 numbers are found : 50, 500, 5000 I want to find this pattern. I tried this:

```
File filesList[] = directoryPath.listFiles(textFileFilter);
System.out.println("List of the text files in the specified directory:");

for(File file : filesList) {

    try {
        try (var br = new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_16)){
            List<CsvLine> beans = new CsvToBeanBuilder(br)
                    .withType(CsvLine.class)
                    .build()
                    .parse();

            Path originalPath = null;

            boolean found50 = false;
            boolean found500 = false;
            boolean found5000 = false;

            for (CsvLine item : beans)
            {
                originalPath = file.toPath();

                if (item.getAvgMonthlySearches() != null)
                {
                    if (item.getValue().compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(50)) == 0)
                    {
                        found50 = true;
                    }

                    if (item.getValue().compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(500)) == 0)
                    {
                        found500 = true;
                    }

                    if (item.getValue().compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(5000)) == 0)
                    {
                        found5000 = true;
                    }
                }

                if(found50 == true && found500 == true && found5000 == true){

                    found50 = false;
                    found500 = false;
                    found5000 = false;

                    // Move here file into new subdirectory when file is invalid
                    Path copied = Paths.get(file.getParent() + "/invalid_files");
                    try {
                        // Use resolve method to keep the "processed" as folder
                        br.close();
                        Files.move(originalPath, copied.resolve(originalPath.getFileName()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                        break;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (file.exists())
            {
                // Move here file into new subdirectory when file processing is finished
                Path copied = Paths.get(file.getParent() + "/processed");
                try {
                    // Use resolve method to keep the "processed" as folder
                    br.close();
                    Files.move(originalPath, copied.resolve(originalPath.getFileName()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                    break;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Path originalPath = file.toPath();
    System.out.println(String.format("\nProcessed file : %s, moving the file to subfolder /processed\n",
            originalPath));
}
```

@Getter
@Setter
public class CsvLine {

```
@CsvBindByPosition(position = 2)
private BigDecimal value;
```

}

I want if I match all values 50, 500 and 5000 on csv file lines to move the current file into a separate folder. I tried to run the code but nothing happens. Do you know where I'm wrong?

Comment: Can you also post *CsvLine* class implementation?

Comment: Q: Have you tried stepping through your code in the debugger?  That's your *FIRST* step.  As I said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75380424/) (now deleted!) post.

Comment: From where get the value the CsvLine object for this expression? `if (item.getAvgMonthlySearches() != null)`?

Comment: Could you post your code, a minimal version that would run, in order for me to take a closer look at it? Maybe post the whole code on *pastebin* or somewhere similar. There is a lot of missing pieces from your code. On line one, I don't know what is a `directoryPath` or a `textFileFilter`. Also, I think the `CsvLine` is incomplete. Are you missing the `getAvgMonthlySearches()` and `getValue()` implementations?

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/rcbandit111/wordscore_sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/wordscore/engine/processor/DataValidationCheckJob.java

Comment: I'm having a problem parsing the csv file due to mismatch between `String` and `BigDecimal`. Can you provide your csv sample file that works for you? It doesn't have to be the whole file.

Comment: yes please edit it to BigDecimal. I will provide the sample file later. See the post it should be the same content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example with more structured code according your needs.
Exception handling is ommitted since I have no idea about your requirements regarding to them, but you can easily adapt this code for your needs.

Also I have no idea what is this `item.getAvgMonthlySearches()`, since I don't see this field  in your csv example. This field and checking of it also ommitted, but you can add it.

The code is decomposed to:

- Main method with preparations and starting the entire directory processing
- method for directory processing
- method for file processing
- method for line processing
- method for moving the file
- factory method for creating predicates ("matchers" or "conditions" that you can specify as much as you want, instead of using "found500" or "found5000" etc.)

I used this csv according to your question:

```
car;score;description 
Opel;30;43 
Volvo;500;434 
Kia;50;3 
Toyota;4;4
Mazda;5000;4
```

So, the model is the following:

```
@Data
public class CsvLine {
    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)
    private BigDecimal value;
}
```

The main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // preparing
    File directory = Path.of("/Users/kerbermeister/csv/").toFile();
    // we want to process only csv files from directory
    FilenameFilter csvFilter = (dir, name) -> name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv");

    // specify what conditions should meet the value of every line
    // to be considered as a valid line
    List<Predicate<BigDecimal>> fileMatchConditions = List.of(
            ne(new BigDecimal("50")),
            ne(new BigDecimal("500")),
            ne(new BigDecimal("5000"))
    );
    // start directory processing
    processDirectory(directory, csvFilter, fileMatchConditions);
}
```

The primary process with the rest methods:

```
public static void processDirectory(File directory, FilenameFilter filter,
                                    List<Predicate<BigDecimal>> fileMatchConditions) throws IOException {

    Path processedFolderPath = createDirectory(Path.of(directory.getAbsolutePath() + "/processed"));
    Path invalidFilesFolderPath = createDirectory(Path.of(directory.getAbsolutePath() + "/invalid_files"));

    File[] files = directory.listFiles(filter);

    if (Objects.nonNull(files)) {
        for (File file : files) {
            if (isFileValid(file, fileMatchConditions)) {
                // if file is valid, then move it to the processed directory
                moveFile(file, processedFolderPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            } else {
                // if file is not, then move it to the invalid-files directory
                moveFile(file, invalidFilesFolderPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * primary file validation
 * parses the file
 */
public static boolean isFileValid(File file, List<Predicate<BigDecimal>> matchConditions) throws IOException {
    try (Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file.getAbsoluteFile().toPath())) {
        List<CsvLine> lineBeans = new CsvToBeanBuilder<CsvLine>(reader)
                .withType(CsvLine.class)
                .withSkipLines(1) // skip header
                .withSeparator(';') // line separator
                .build()
                .parse();

        // unique violations found within this file
        Set<BigDecimal> violations = new HashSet<>();
        for (CsvLine line : lineBeans) {
            // skip if value in the line is null
            if (Objects.isNull(line.getValue())) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!isLineValid(line, matchConditions)) {
                violations.add(line.getValue());
            }
            // if we reached all the violations, then file is not valid
            if (violations.size() == matchConditions.size()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * if all predicates return true, then line is valid
 */
public static boolean isLineValid(CsvLine line, List<Predicate<BigDecimal>> conditions) {
    return conditions.stream().allMatch(predicate -> predicate.test(line.getValue()));
}

/**
 * move the file to the directory specified
 */
public static void moveFile(File file, Path moveTo, StandardCopyOption option) throws IOException {
    Files.move(file.toPath(), moveTo.resolve(file.getName()), option);
}

/**
 * factory method for Predicate that returns true if compareTo != 0
 */
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Predicate<T> ne(T target) {
    return (value) -> value.compareTo(target) != 0;
}

public static Path createDirectory(Path path) throws IOException {
    if (!Files.exists(path) || !Files.isDirectory(path)) {
        return Files.createDirectory(path);
    }
    return path;
}
```

So, I think you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I found one issue. There are cases when the table role value is empty and I get error `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Comparable.compareTo(Object)" because "value" is null
` at this line `return (value) -> value.compareTo(target) != 0;` can you advice what is the proper way to skip this line if it's empty?

Comment: added null checking